# Linq -how to select and compare if an item exist , from a list

Tags: c#, linq

[image]
t.id means the room the user is looking those amenities

I have a multiple selection list. I am trying to found out if each item selected by the user exist on my main list. For example, the user selects chairs and desks, and my main list has 18 items on each. Some have chairs, some have tables or some have both.
I need a query that lets me identify what items on the main list contain the items selected by the user .
This is what I have.

[image]

```
var filtered = availableMainList
    .Where(p => selectamenities
        .All(o => p.amenities.Exists(t => t.id == o)))
    .Where(t => t.id == roomid)
    .ToList();
```

so lets say , user selects chair and desk , but availableMainList only have one room with chair and the other room with the desk , then it returns 0 , I want it to return each room that has a chair even thought doesn't have the other items.

Comment: So a user selects chair and desk and you only want the chair room, not the desk room too?

Comment: So `All` => `Any`? Perhaps if you add an example input (for `availableMainList` and `selectamenities`) and expected output it's easier to understand your goal.

Comment: @NetMage and then why does it switch from `p` to `t`, where they are both the same object?

Comment: so you are answering a question with another question ? not helpful

Comment: Your question needs details as suggested by @Xerillio - perhaps if you added them, we would be able to help you.